# How do I load an image into three.js?

Tags: three.js

I'm new to three.js and am trying to map an image onto an object. However, I'm not sure where or how to include the image in the image loader.

```
var imgTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "http://threejs.org/examples/textures/disturb.jpg" );

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: imgTexture });

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100,32,16);

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);

sphere.position.x=0;    
sphere.position.y=0;    
sphere.position.z=0;    
scene.add(sphere);
```

Including the image as a link like shown above doesn't work, nor does including it as a local file, so now I'm just really confused. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you also add where the material is applied? Your loading seems not to be the problem (as a local file).

Comment: I just added it, I just assumed it would be applied the normal way.

Comment: Still can't see anything wrong there. Are you sure your local path is correct? For example `"images/examples/textures/disturb.jpg"`

Comment: I think so. I just used /Users/me/Desktop/disturb.jpg

Comment: I believe that might be the problem. Try placing the image inside your project in a img folder and link it like `"img/disturb.jpg"`

Comment: Is an image folder different than a regular folder? I just placed a folder called img in the same folder as where I included everything else.

Comment: I figured it out, turns out Chrome doesn't like me using local files... using safari did the trick. Thank you for your help!

Comment: good to hear it works